# How to code a variable from one dataframe to another for time-series

Tags: r

I have data that looks something like this:

```
**country**        **regstdate**    **regenddate**  
U.K.                1824                1918
Austria-Hungary     1800                1865
Japan               1800                1945
China               1965                2019
.
.
.
Russia              1815                2010
```

and another country-dyad dataset that looks something like this:

```
**country_1**     **country_2**    **reg_power1**    **reg_power2**.   **year**
U.K.                USA                 NA                NA           1823
U.K.                USA                 NA                NA             1824
U.K.                USA                 NA                NA             1825
U.K.                USA                 NA                NA             1826
.
.
.
U.K.                USA                 NA                NA             1918
```

Basically what I'm trying to do and can't quite seem to figure out is to code a dummy variable for all year for which either `country_1` or  `country_2` is a "regional power" (`reg_power1` or `reg_power2`) for the years that those countries began and ended as regional powers (`regstdate` and `regenddate`). The second dataset would end up looking something like this:

```
**country_1**     **country_2**    **reg_power1**    **reg_power2**.   **year**
U.K.                 USA                 1                 0             1823
U.K.                 USA                 1                 0             1824
U.K.                 USA                 1                 0             1825
U.K.                 USA                 1                 0             1826
.
.
.
U.K.                 USA                 0                0              1918
```

I have tried this:

```
dyads$reg_power1 <- ifelse(dyads$ccode1 == reg_power$ccode & 
                           dyads$year >= reg_power$regstyear &
                           dyads$year <= reg_power$regendyear, 1, 0)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Produce small but representative example data set, and post it here, using `dput()`, I'ts hard to give an answer without data.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Data
C<-c("U.K.","Austria-Hungary","Japan","China","Russia")
Y0<-c(1824,1800,1800,1965,1815)
Y1<-c(1918,1865,1945,2019,2010)
df<-cbind(C,Y0,Y1)
df2<-expand.grid(C,C,min(Y0):max(Y1))
df2<-df2[!df2[,1]==df2[,2],]
names(df2)<-c("country1","country2","year")
```

and

```
#Solution
sol<-merge(df2,df[,c(1,2)],by.x="country1",by.y="C",all=T)
sol<-merge(sol,df[,c(1,3)],by.x="country2",by.y="C",all=T)
sol$reg_power1<-ifelse(sol$year==sol$Y0,1,0)
sol$reg_power2<-ifelse(sol$year==sol$Y1,1,0)
sol<-sol[,c(2,1,6,7,3)]
```